# Can not get data after compare two tables

Tags: asp.net, linq

I have 2 tables which have their own slug. I want to compare slug by an action to filter the post to show on view to user. This is my LINQ, but it's not working.

```
public ActionResult BaiViet(string slugCategory, string slugPost)
{
    var model = db.Posts.Single(p => p.slug.Equals(slugPost)
                                     && p.catID.Equals(db.Categories.Single(c => c.slug.Equals(slugCategory)).catID)
                    );
    return View(model);
}
```

I tried this but still not working :(

```
public ActionResult BaiViet(string slugCategory, string slugPost)
{
    var model = (from c in db.Categories
                 from p in db.Posts
                 where c.catID == p.catID
                       && c.slug == slugPost
                       && p.slug == slugCategory
                 select p).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: Can you post the tables as well?

Comment: c.slug == slugCategory && p.slub == slugPost, are you comparing post with category?

Comment: not working ??? is not a question..either post your error or your requirement

Comment: have found my resolution to this question, thanks everyone

Comment: if you have found a solution, post it as an asnwer below. I did it for you this time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution posted by author in his original post:

```
var model = (from p in db.Posts
                join c in db.Categories
                    on p.catID equals c.catID
                where
                    p.slugPost == slugbaiviet
                    && c.slugCat == slugchuyenmuc
                select p).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: You should probably mark your post as "community wiki" if you've just copied and pasted the answer from the original post. That way, you won't get the credit for the work the OP put in if the answer is upvoted (alternatively, you won't *lose* reputation if it is downvoted).